# Loading 'quests' with Java Nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

I've been working on my own script engine for a while until I discovered Nashorn. Quick analysys lead me to belive that it's what I want, but also left me with some design questions.

I am trying to develop custom quest loader that would allow me to load custom quests from files and then assign those to players.

My problem is mostly with design since I don't know how script-based code works internally (performance). Currently I have a set of different classes (in Java) such as: (note "..." means "some args").

- Quest - description of what the quest is about, has methods such as "onStart(...)", "onFinish(...)". Holds list of all tasks that this quest requires to be finished, from which some are assigned to player in "onStart" (meaning they are starting points). Note that Quest is a BASE class, created only once and stored in quest registry, then when assigned to player, the player gets his own QuestHolder which points at Quest.
- Task - description of some step in quest, can be an IListener or not - in which case it will "complete()" only when something from outside will order completion. Task can also assign next task from mentioned Quest's all task list.
- IListener - base for MANY (dozens) extending interfaces like "IListenerKill", "IListenerTravel" or "IListenerPlace" (quite self explainatory). Listeners are hooked to entity (e.g player) they were assigned to and will call proper methods upon action. If task implements some IListener it can listen to entity's actions and know when it's being completed.
- QuestHolder - data-holding object of Quest.
- Some other stuff, but above are most important.

Now, what I need from Nashorn is to be able to load multiple Quests from multiple files (/questDir/QuestName.js) and create "new Quest()" for them.

For example (pseudo-script): "/questDir/MerryChristmas.js"

```
Quest q = new Quest("MerryChristmas");
Task t = new TaskKill("Kill elfs and snowmans terrorizing city!");
t.addTarget(Target.SNOWMAN, 5); // Task will listen to those kills.
t.addTarget(Target.Elf, 2);
t.setRequirements(new RequirementLevel(10)); // Every task can have requirements needed to even begin it, if some other task will try to apply task of which player is not fulfilling requirements, it won't be assigned until condition is met (tracked internally with events).
t.addNext("Come Back for present!"); // Upon completing, will assign task with this name, if one is found in Quest's all task list.
q.addTask(t);
q.addStartingTask(t);
t = new TaskTalk(Type.NPC, "Come back for present!");
t.setTarget("Santa Claus"); // some npc's name.
q.addTask(t);
```

Again - this is totally pseudo-script, but I need to be able to load "parse" such scripts into Java objects (quests).

Next thing I want to learn: Approach above makes use of alredy existing stuff, all objects (tasks and listeners) are pre-prepared and are handled by game itself. I'd like to go further and create custom objects inside script.

Say - I'd want to also have an if statement inside TaskKill that would "count kill" of Snowman, only if he was killed with torch (e.g quest like: "Burn those snowmen!"). Sure I can go and extend each of my Task and IListener classes to check for additional stuff (similar to ".addRequirement(...)" in pseudo sample from before), but that will NEVER be "cover-any-case". Question is: How can one extend Class and method of Java class from within script?

Finally: Scripts are loaded on server. Game is MP. For everything that is included on Java side (e.g: TaskKill), client is able to replicate ANY quest that was loaded on server, but (if, from previous question - making sub-classes with scripts is possible) then client cannot cover all cases.
Would it be as simple as sending script sctring over network and evaluate script on client to get it working?

Thanks for any links, codes, sources, explanations!

Comment: @markspace I don't really see myself (or anyone in that matter) compiling tons of quests from dev. env. Not every admin (user of engine/game) can even code in Java, and script language, while still requires some knowledge, is still code-able after some short tutorials or simple templates. Also, you can do it very remotely (it's text-based :P).

Comment: Okay, so I cannot extend Classes, how about making Java object's method like: TaskKill#shouldCount(Player player, Target target), which would call a method inside script that would return boolean. That method could make some checks, wouldn't it? Note: I only know little about scripting as a whole, so my questions might be obviously bad.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can extend Java classes in Nashorn scripts. See https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-java_extend And you can call super class methods as well
 https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/Nashorn/Nashorn+extensions#Nashornextensions-java_super